# Getting rid of empty boxes in LaTeX table

Tags: tables

I am pretty new to LaTeX and i'm struggling with multicolumn/multirow tables. I have a table that has two empty boxes on the inside of it. I want to remove those boxes without changing the layout of the table in anyway. I know it's a really simple question, but for some reason i can't managed to find a solution :(

Here is the code i have for the table

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{A Confusion Matrix for the J48 Baseline}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Confusion Matrix}\\
\hline
&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Predicted}\\
\hline
&Category& 0-1 & 2-10 & 11-200  \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Truth Data}
&0-1&17964 & 2437& 1210\\ 
&2-10&5093 & 11334 & 5209 \\
&11-200 &1519& 3302 & 16638\\ [1ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:3}
\end{table}
```

[image: The LaTeX table]

Comment: You say you want to get rid of those two boxes.  Does that mean you want to delete the vertical lines to the left of those boxes and also the horizontal line separating those two boxes?

Comment: You can use  `\cline{2-5}`in the place of the third `\hline`.

Comment: Note that in general vertical lines in tables aren't recommended anymore. They actually makes the table harder to read. See the `booktabs` package for better horizontal lines (that are not compatible with vertical lines)

Comment: @James Hi James, yes i guess it would mean removing both

Comment: @Bernard,  Thank you i will have a look at your suggestion now

Comment: @daleif That's good advice and i hadn't realised that thank you, i will take a look at that package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? It does not look that nice.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hhline}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{A Confusion Matrix for the J48 Baseline}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Confusion Matrix}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Predicted}\\
        \hhline{~|----|}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&Category& 0-1 & 2-10 & 11-200  \\ [0.5ex] 
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Truth Data}
        &0-1&17964 & 2437& 1210\\ 
        &2-10&5093 & 11334 & 5209 \\
        &11-200 &1519& 3302 & 16638\\ [1ex] 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:3}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is better but not that great either

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hhline}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{A Confusion Matrix for the J48 Baseline}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
        \hhline{~|----|}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Confusion Matrix}\\
        \hhline{~|----|}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Predicted}\\
        \hhline{~|----|}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&Category& 0-1 & 2-10 & 11-200  \\ [0.5ex] 
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Truth Data}
        &0-1&17964 & 2437& 1210\\ 
        &2-10&5093 & 11334 & 5209 \\
        &11-200 &1519& 3302 & 16638\\ [1ex] 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:3}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The latter table is perfect and exactly what i wanted.  I know it doesn't look ideal but i'm very happy with that, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I'd make some small, but important, adjustments in order to reduce ugliness.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the picture

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{A Confusion Matrix for the J48 Baseline}
\label{table:3}

\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Confusion Matrix}\\
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Predicted}\\
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \smash{Category} & 0--1 & 2--10 & 11--200  \\
\hline
\multirow{3.5}{*}{Truth Data}
&  0--1   & 17964 &  2437 &  1210 \\ 
&  2--10  &  5093 & 11334 &  5209 \\
& 11--200 &  1519 &  3302 & 16638 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{A Confusion Matrix for the J48 Baseline}
\label{foo}

\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells

\begin{tabular}{c|cccc|} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Confusion Matrix}\\
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Predicted}\\
%\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \smash{Category} & 0--1 & 2--10 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11--200}  \\
\cline{2-5}
\multirow{3.5}{*}{\makebox[0pt][r]{Truth Data}}
&  0--1   & 17964 &  2437 &  1210 \\ 
&  2--10  &  5093 & 11334 &  5209 \\
& 11--200 &  1519 &  3302 & 16638 \\ 
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I also added a different version that you may find more appealing.
The black corner in the second picture shows the left margin. Remove `\usepackage{showframe}` for the production version.

[image]